# Python: Assign the value of an undefined (but necessary) variable in a python script, from another script

Tags: python, function, variables, python-import

I was wondering if there is a way of doing the following:

I have a program, call it `a.py`. Here there are some functions and stuff. For some of these functions, there is a variable (is part of the settings of the functions, let's say), call it `myvar`. This variable is not an argument of them, just a setting! So for instance

`def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
         return arg1*arg2 - myvar`
This variable hasn't been defined in the program `a.py`.

Now I want to create another program `b.py`, here I want to use the output of the above program, but each time I need to change the value of the variable. Something like

`import a
list1 = []
for j in range(10):
        myvar = j
        list1.append(a.myfunc(arg1, arg2))`

I hope what I want to do is clear. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: *Pass it as argument.* It's that simple. Effectively it *is* an argument to the function, you're just trying to implicitly pass it, which is madness. *Maybe* you want a class and set that value as a property.

Comment: @deceze the point is that I can't do it!

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: @deceze because when I do that I get totally different results for some reason

Comment: Then maybe tackle *that* issue, because passing it as an argument is the only thing that makes sense from what you describe.

Comment: @deceze I will try, but this would solve everything

Answer (score 2):

If you just set `a.myvar` from `b` you should be fine. For example:

```
a.py
----------------
test = 10

def foo():
    print(test)


b.py
----------------
import a

a.foo()
a.test = 100 
a.foo()
```

will output

```
10
100
```

Note: Except for very niche applications, you should not be doing this and should very likely be using a function parameter.

Comment: While this solution may do what the OP wants, it shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I agree that in most cases this is bad practice (and based on the comments of OP on his question it seems like OP just doesn't know what they're doing) but for future people that find this with a legitimate application at least they will see that they can do it instead of just "Don't do that"

Comment: I would recommend an answer along the lines of... "yeah, you _could_ do this... but here's a better way: ".